# Run logic after window is shown

Tags: javafx

I have a small program which gets called by another program, downloads/renames some files and closes itself afterwards. I want to show the user the progress with some simple text. My problem is, that the logic of the code runs before the view is completely shown. The window is visible but the content (in this case the sample text) is not.

I have already tried setOnShown() (as seen in my example) or setOnShowning(). I also tried not using a fxml file for the layout. But nothing seems to work.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        Text t = new Text();
        t.setText("sample Text");
        root.getChildren().add(t);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setOnShown(e -> {
            updaterLogic(); //do some work
        });
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void updaterLogic(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I want the view to be completed before running the actual logic. How can i archieve this?

Comment: The window is shown, but the contant of the window is not. It looks like this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/65J061V)

Comment: i have updated the question. The `updaterLogic` function waits for 10 seconds and should be called after the view is fully shown. But it doesn't. The text "sample Text" is not visible during this duration and only shown after the function has passed.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed my problem. Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions! Can i somehow mark this as the offcial answer?

Answer (score 0):

To execute something after a window has been shown you can:

1. Listen for a `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN` event.

   - See `Window.onShown` and `Window.addEventHandler`
2. Listen to the `Window.showing` property and react when it changes to `true`.
3. Put the code after the call to `show()`.

   - But not `showAndWait()` as that method doesn't return until the window is closed (and is illegal to call on the primary stage).

However, how to do this is not your problem (you're already using `onShown`). Your problem is caused by how you execute the "updater logic". Inside your `updaterLogic()` method you are calling `Thread.sleep` (simulating work). Since event handlers are executed on the *JavaFX Application Thread* that causes said thread to block. While the FX thread is blocked it can't do anything related to the GUI (e.g. layout passes, trigger rendering pulses, process user events, etc...)—thus the frozen window with no content rendered.

Move the "updater logic" onto a background thread so that the FX thread remains free to do its work. For general information about concurrency in Java, see [Lesson: Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and the [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. For JavaFX specifics, see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), the [`javafx.concurrent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) package, and [`Platform.runLater(Runnable)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)).

Here are two golden rules of JavaFX:

1. You **must never** block, nor execute long running work on, the *JavaFX Application Thread*.
2. You **must always** access and modify a live scene graph on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

   - This is documented by [`Node`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html):

     > Node objects may be constructed and modified on any thread as long they are not yet attached to a Scene in a Window that is showing. An application must attach nodes to such a Scene or modify them on the JavaFX Application Thread.

     *Note: Some nodes, such as [`WebView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html), must be created on the FX thread; this will be documented as appropriate.*